# iOS 7 CBCentral identifier unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, core-bluetooth

I am using `CoreBluetooth` in Objective C to connect two or more iOS devices. I've successfully done this is the past and it is working in case of this project as well, but I bumped into an interesting and rather annoying issue.

When I discover the peripheral, I connect to it, then subscribe to the characteristics - in this moment, in the function:

```
- (void) peripheralManager:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral central:(CBCentral *)central didSubscribeToCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)thisCharacteristic
```

I get the central object, which subscribes to the characteristics, however, when I try to get its identifier, I get the following error, crashing the app:

```
-[CBCentral identifier]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x20073dc0
```

The interesting part is, that this issue occurs only if the central is running iOS 7, with iOS 6 there are no problems, the identifier contains a correct value.

I'd like to also mention, that the UUID deprecated parameter returns the correct value also for iOS7.

Does anybody have an idea? How can I fix this problem? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure its not backwards? The error you report should happen in iOS 6 devices since this property should not be available in them. About the UUID, there is no reason why it wouldn't return the correct value. It is deprecated but still working, so ideally you should call "identifier" for iOS 7+ devices, and UUID for iOS 5-6 devices.

Comment: How did I miss this? Thanks for your help Chiquis! Sometimes, when you've dug yourself deep enough, you seize to see the obvious :)

Comment: ill paste the comment as an answer so you can accept it, or you could delete the question if you prefer, either way having open questions is not that good. cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The error you report should happen in iOS 6 devices since this property should not be available in them. About the UUID, there is no reason why it wouldn't return the correct value. It is deprecated but still working, so ideally you should call "identifier" for iOS 7+ devices, and UUID for iOS 5-6 devices.